# Почему не применяется шрифт при создании PDF-документа?

Tags: java, .net, pdf, itext

Я создаю PDF-документы с помощью iText. Когда я пытаюсь включить шрифт «Agenda Tabular Light», iText игнорирует мой выбор. В этом можно убедиться на вкладке Файл > Свойства > Шрифты в Adobe Reader. PDF-файл показывает, что используется шрифт Helvetica, хотя этот шрифт выбран не был. Отображаются цвета, но не шрифт.
Мой код выглядит так:

```
public static final Font FONT_HEADER = FontFactory.getFont(AGENDA_TABULAR_LIGHT, 18, Font.NORMAL, TITLE_COLOR);
```

Также была проведена проверка в программе-примере.

```
// step 1
Document document = new Document();
// step 2
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
// step 3 
document.open(); 
// step 4: 
Font font = FontFactory.getFont("Agenda Tabular Light");
System.out.println(font.toString()); 
document.add(new Phrase("Agenda Tabular Light J j", font)); 
Font fontbold = FontFactory.getFont("Times-Roman", 12, Font.BOLD);
document.add(new Phrase("Times-Roman, Bold", fontbold)); 
document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
document.close();
```

Здесь отображается шрифт Times-Roman, но по факту используется другой шрифт. Каждый раз на вкладке свойств шрифта в Adobe Reader отображается Helvetica.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474125/times-new-roman-font-in-itext-java-version

Comment: Вот здесь есть ответ на ваш вопрос [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556678/unicode-characters-in-itext-pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556678/unicode-characters-in-itext-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию FontProgramFactory (FontFactory в iText 5) знает только шрифты типа 1, а шрифт "garamond bold" не входит в этот список, поэтому используется Helvetica (Helvetica — шрифт по умолчанию в iText).
Можно «научить» FontProgramFactory, как находить другие шрифты, зарегистрировав их. Можно попробовать следующее:

```
FontProgramFactory.registerSystemFontDirectories();
```

Но это очень затратная операция, так как здесь iText ищет в вашей операционной системе файлы шрифтов в разных каталогах (например, в C:/Windows/Fonts). Это может занять несколько секунд, и на выходе получится намного больше шрифтов, чем необходимо (возможно, что нужный шрифт так и не будет зарегистрирован).
Лучше регистрировать шрифты следующим образом.

```
FontProgramFactory.registerFont("c:/windows/fonts/garabd.ttf", "garamond bold");
```

Мы сообщаем iText, где найти файл .ttf ("c:/windows/fonts/garabd.ttf") и определяем псевдоним для нужного шрифта («garamond bold»). Теперь, когда название шрифта зарегистрировано, его можно использовать:

```
PdfFont myBoldFont = PdfFontFactory.createRegisteredFont("garamond bold");
```